# Xcode - View controller inside navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uidatepicker

I have set up a navigation controller, and the view controller within that is set to the class of another view controller I have already created. The problem is, I have a UIDatePicker snapped to the bottom of the latter view controller, and when the app loads up the UIDatePicker is partially obscured.

Obviously this is because the height of the second view controller is larger than that of the view controller within the navigation controller.

I'm sorry, I know this all sound confusing, but can anyone help me out?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the frames of both the view and the UIDatePicker so they do not obscure one another.

Answer (score 0):

Set the view1 ad view2 height that doesn't obscure the date picker (As you cannot change the size of a datePicker).